# Infraestructura DBA

Tags: sql-server

Well, I'm newbie, now only to realize at the nick. I am developing an online system, which will have information from several companies. Each company has its desktop system with the local database. A firm is independent of the other.

The web site will be loaded with important information of each company.

The database is MSSQL. At first I thought about using replication to replicate the data needed for the web site for the MSSQL database site web site, so just redeem the information locally and show pro user.

However, I doubt if this is correct this way. A little time discovering the tool SymmetricDS, a synchronization tool database, regardless of platform.

Which method for synchronizing x company website would be better? Own replication or MSSQL SymmetricDS (http://www.symmetricds.org)?

==================================================================================

Olá! Bem, sou novato, já da para perceber apenas pelo nick. Estou desenvolvendo um sistema online, onde terá informações de várias empresas. Cada empresa tem o seu sistema desktop, com banco de dados local. Uma empresa é independente da outra.

O web site será carregado com informações importantes de cada empresa.

O Banco de dados é MSSQL. A principio pensei em utilizar replicação, para replicar os dados necessários para o web site, para o banco de dados MSSQL local do web site, sendo assim, apenas resgataria as informações localmente e mostraria pro usuário.

Porém, me vem a dúvida se esta correto este modo. A pouco tempo descobrir a ferramente symmetricDS, uma ferramenta de sincronização de banco de dados, independente da plataforma.

Qual método para sincronização de empresa x website seria melhor? Própria replicação do MSSQL ou SymmetricDS ( http://www.symmetricds.org ) ?

Answer (score 1):

Let me anser with a stupid question - why add a third party software for a stack (sql servr) you totally control? Why doing so IGNORING THE MICROSOFT SYNC FRAMEWORK THAT ALSO EXISTS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/)?

THere may be valid reasons, but I Generally start with a "as few companies and products in the game as possible". So, waht is the reason to use another software? Not being snippy here, but for me the decision is simple - UNLESS I can come up with a reason to add more technology to my stack, I do not do it. Makes things easier to maintain, cheaper to upgrade etc.

On top, we don't do product recommendations. Especially as you seem to have just spend 10 seconds on google - there are a LOT more alternatives than you mention.

Comment: Friend, not to be stupid, but if you just started a discussion was because I know all alternatives.

I will take a look at this tool.